# What was the disease Moriarty used?

Tags: plot-explanation, sherlock-holmes-a-game-of-shadows

In *Sherlock Holmes: A Game of Shadows*, Moriarty uses a deadly disease on Irene Adler which caused near-instant death.

- What was this disease?
- And why didn't Moriarty use it on Watson and his wife during the murder
  attempt?

I realize that the last question can be chalked up to just a plot device, but I don't know if I missed a reason why he never used it again.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

He stated, to Sherlock, that it was a strain of tuberculosis.

> **Moriarty:** *The strain proves too much for her, and she suddenly falls ill...with tragic consequences. **A rare form of tuberculosis.** She succumbed in a matter of seconds.*

As far as I can determine, he killed off the girl rather directly because she was a major loose end in his plans.  He sent the “assassins” to kill the Watsons to A) Distract Sherlock, and B) To state that they weren't safe, no matter what.